# Extracting data from a given string pattern

Tags: objective-c

Given the following pattern: "##-##-##", where "##" represents a 1 or 2 digit integer, what is the best way to separate the numbers?

Some background: I have an array of NSString objects. From this array I create a new mutable array, converting some of the strings into NSNumbers (this is working). Some of the strings have the pattern shown above (the pattern represents wins, losses and ties). I want to add to the mutable array, the string (as is) as well as the wins, losses, and ties as NSIntegers.

I don't know if it would be better to use an NSScanner or NSRegularExpression. I have not used either of these before and I'm not sure how to set them up and return the info that I need.

Thanks in advance,
Brad

Comment: Some people prefer NSScanner, and other prefer NSRegularExpression. For this task, both would work. Or simply use componentsSeparatedByString ...

Comment: @MartinR I hadn't thought of using componentsSeparatedByString. It'll be easy to cycle through the resulting array to add each object to the mutable array. How to I check for the pattern though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use NSRegularExpression then try like this:-

```
 NSRegularExpression *regex = 
 [NSRegularExpression 
 regularExpressionWithPattern:@"-"
options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
error:nil];

NSArray *matches = [regex 
 matchesInString:string  options:0
 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]`. For your case is simple. The rest I believe it is overkill.

```
NSString *completeString= @"20-33-89";
NSArray *numbers = [completeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```